# splitting a column in r

Tags: r, split

I have the following data frame in R and I am trying to split the tags by the vertical bar and and as a new row.

In theory I want to be able to see the different tags by videoid or other variables. I am able to split the tags, but not to link them to the video.

```
zz  <- data.frame(x$video_id, FOO=x$tags)
```

but not sure how to continue...

The code below only allows me to separate the tags

```
tags <- as.character(x$tags)
tags <- strsplit(as.character(x$tags), "\\|")
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(tags)))
df <- table(df) #table of df
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

The dataframe

[image]

Comment: Hi @Kenia Cevallos, please find here some help on how to write a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, i.e. instead of posting a screenshot of your data, please actually include it in the code.

Comment: Probably, what you need is `df1 <- tidyr::separate_rows(x, tags, "\\|")`